# How to reshape a dataset for 1D CNN?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, time-series, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train a data set of 50352 rows with 4 columns. It is a classification problem with 4 different classes. How can I reshape the data set so that it can be used for 1D-CNN?

Just for reference following is my code.

1. Reshaping the data

   ```
   x_train = x_scaled_test.reshape(50352, 4, 1)
   ```
2. Defining and compiling the data

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(64, 2, input_shape=(4, 1), activation='relu'))  # convolation

model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=2))  # pooling
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())  # flatten

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))  # fc

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))  # dropout

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
                  optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
```

3. Fitting the model

```
verbose, epochs, batch_size = 0, 10, 32
model.fit(x_train, Y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
```

I am getting this error

```
raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other)) ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 4) are incompatible
```

Comment: Please **format** your code snippets (done it for you this time)

Comment: Really sorry for that, Thank you so much. can you suggest where I am going wrong with the code?

Comment: What is the shape of the array containing the labels? The shape of the labels ( passed the model ) is `( None , 1  )`  but the last `Dense` layer has 4 units, which isn't compatible with `categorical_crossentropy` function.

Comment: The shape of labels is as follows.

` (50352, 1) `  50352 rows with one column, which has 4 different categorical classes. Do I need to reshape it? -@ShubhamPanchal